# How to extract file contents from a Buffer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs, multer

I am just exploring the Node.js and came across a problem while creating functionality to upload small files to memory using `multer` module.

I am using the built-in `MemoryStorage` option for `multer`. The file gets uploaded successfully, and the file metadata becomes accessible in the `req` object of `ExpressJS`.

Now what I'd like to be able to be to read the file contents from the Buffer, as this file will be in .csv format, which would later be converted to JSON. I need the string contents of the files to perform the conversion.

Here is my router handler:

```
const memStorage = multer.memoryStorage();
const memUpload = multer({
  storage: memStorage,
  limits: { fileSize: 30 * 1024 * 2014, files: 1 }
});
router.post(
  '/tables/csv',
  memUpload.single('file'),
  (req, res) => {
    const file = req.file;
    let buffer = fs.readFileSync(file.buffer);
    console.log(buffer);
  }
);
```

.csv file used:

```
Risk Category,Risk ID,Risk Value
Some,Some,Some
Some,Some,Some
Some,Some,Some
```

Console Output:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'Risk Category,Risk ID,Risk Value
Some,Some,Some
Some,Some,Some
Some,Some,Some'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:436:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:341:35)
    at router.post (C:\client_projects\tt\sarcs-hotline\router\index.js:1039:21)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\client_projects\tt\sarcs-hotline\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\client_projects\tt\sarcs-hotline\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Array.<anonymous> (C:\client_projects\tt\sarcs-hotline\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:53:37)
    at listener (C:\client_projects\tt\sarcs-hotline\node_modules\on-finished\index.js:169:15)
    at onFinish (C:\client_projects\tt\sarcs-hotline\node_modules\on-finished\index.js:100:5)
    at callback (C:\client_projects\tt\sarcs-hotline\node_modules\ee-first\index.js:55:10)
    at IncomingMessage.onevent (C:\client_projects\tt\sarcs-hotline\node_modules\ee-first\index.js:93:5)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1094:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify your encoding when calling `fs.readFileSync` to get a string:

```
fs.readFileSync(file.buffer, { encoding: 'utf8' });
```

Alternativly you dont need `readFileSync`. You can just call `buffer.toString(encoding)` like

```
file.buffer.toString('utf8');
```